# MySQL Passing column with missing row to JSON_OBJECT makes that object fail to JSON_EXTRACT properly

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36eb99b01a45214888921dc28d8efed2) illustrating this issue.

Let's say there are two tables: `table_one` containing a single `id` column and `table_two` containing an `id` column and an `other` column.

`table_one` has values `id=1` and `id=2`.
`table_two` has value `id=1, other=5`

The following query will return no results:

```
SELECT id, other
FROM table_one
LEFT JOIN table_two USING (id)
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT (JSON_OBJECT ('id', id, 'other', other), "$.id") = 2
```

While this query will return correctly:

```
SELECT id, other
FROM table_one
LEFT JOIN table_two USING (id)
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT (JSON_OBJECT ('id', id, 'other', NULL), "$.id") = 2
```

In both cases, other evaluates to `NULL`. What's different about the 1st case that causes it to fail?

Comment: Looks like a bug. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43a9ebb16acbba328c7fd79fd4cae890

Comment: Definitely could be. Reported it as a bug to MySQL - will update here if I receive any communication from them.